# flashdevelop seems did not target on Flash player 11

Tags: flashdevelop

I'm developing actionscript on FlashDevelop. I've install adobe flash player 11 plugin in windows. (Although I'm not really sure which file I should download).
http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

And I also have flex sdk 4.5.1 and made a folder 11.0 with playerglobal.swc.
After all, I create a AS3, and target it to flash player 11.0, however it still pop out a flash player 10.0.

How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FlashDevelop uses the "Projector content debugger" (see in FP downloads), not your browser plugin.

- To use this new standalone Flash player it should be associated with SWF files so FD will use it automatically - if it doesn't work, you can specify the path to this EXE in FD program settings > FlashViewer > External Player Path.
- Another option, if you want to open a web browser instead, is to change in Project Properties > Output > 'Test Movie Mode' to 'Open Document' and click Edit... to enter 'bin/index.html'.